# How to update number in db using php loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update data in database. For this purpose i use this code for update order_no in db. But the problem is when i try this $x <= 10 then 10 is update any where in db. And i need to update in db like this 0123456789

Here is my code Example

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x++) {
    echo $sql = "UPDATE `images` SET `order_no`= $x WHERE `category_id` = 40 AND `image_type` = 'Book Image'";

    if ($GLOBALS['link']->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
        //echo md5($newPassword);
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $link->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: use $x < 10....but why you doing this its not correct ...

Comment: if you try with that for($x = 0; $x < 5; $x++)... note the stop condition in the for definition < instead <=

Comment: you want like UPDATE `images` SET `order_no`='0123456789' ?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You're updating the `order_no` field of all matching rows over and over again in your loop. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you want to update the `order_no` of the first matching row to `0`, the second row to `1`, the third to `2` and so on?

Comment: You can not give order no like this. Your approach is wrong. Because at each loop its updaing the order_no as x. Finally all the rows will have the same order no. for the selected category id and image type.

Comment: If you want to give order no. of the images, it should be give at the time of insertion. Its the best method i know.

Comment: If there is no option to give order no. only by update. first you have to find the total no. of rows exist with category id and image_type. Then give this total rows as the limit of the loop. Then in the query give limit and offset to select a particular rows. this might work

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 9; $x++) {
    //Your code here
}
```

And not  **$x <= 10**
A+

Answer (score 0):

i dun know what's your purpose to do this, but if u want to update like 
0123456789, you should use

```
for($x=0;$x<=9;$x++){
    //your code
}
```

or

```
for($x=0;$x<10;$x++){
    //your code
}
```

but as i known in ur sql, all your order no in  `category_id` = 40 AND `image_type` = Book Image will become 9

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to `insert order no.` of the image folder is `at the time of insertion`. Your approach is wrong. Problem with your code is, after the loop gets completed, the order no. `will be same all the rows` of selected category and image type.

But right now if you doesn't have any other options except `UPDATE`, first you have to `find the total no. of rows exist` with selected category_id and image_type. Then use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to get the specified rows.

Please use the below code if your doesn't have any other option.

```
// first find the total no. of rows exist with the selected category_id and image_type
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as total_count  from `images` WHERE `category_id` = 40 AND `image_type` = 'Book Image'";
$result = query($sql);
$total_count = $result->fetch_row()['total_count'];

// give the total row count as the limit
for ($x = 0; $x <= $total_count; $x++) {
    // use LIMIT and OFFSET to select the specified rows
    $sql = "UPDATE `images` SET `order_no`= $x WHERE `category_id` = 40 AND `image_type` = 'Book Image' LIMIT 1 OFFSET $x";

    if ($GLOBALS['link']->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
        //echo md5($newPassword);
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $link->error;
    }
}
```

If my post code have any issue please find the appropriate code. But there is no issue in the logic.